# Win10 <-> USB <-> Arduino - Problem to communicate with Autohotkey

Tags: arduino, usb, autohotkey, communication

My desire is to communicate with an **Arduino Uno** over an USB-port (**COM3 - 9600,N,8,1**).
I was going to manage the information with Autohotkey on a computer running **Windows 10**.

This test is only intended to read the information from the Arduino. But later I also want to be able to send information from the PC to the Arduino Uno.

The Arduino Uno has an extra card attached (Funduino JoyStick Shield V1.A) - only for the test.

This is the program I use on the Arduino .:

```
// Armuino --- Funduino Joystick Shield ---
// Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRFnGJH1nJiKIpz_ZyaU-uAZOkMH8GAcw
//
// Part 1. Introduction - Basic Functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZPZuBCFMH4

// Arduino digital pins associated with buttons
const byte PIN_BUTTON_A = 2; 
const byte PIN_BUTTON_B = 3;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_C = 4;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_D = 5;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_E = 6;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_F = 7;

// Arduino analog pins associated with joystick
const byte PIN_ANALOG_X = 0;
const byte PIN_ANALOG_Y = 1;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_B, INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_B, HIGH);

  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_E, INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_E, HIGH);

  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_C, INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_C, HIGH);

  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_D, INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_D, HIGH);

  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_A, INPUT);  
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_A, HIGH);  
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Buttons A:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON_A));
  Serial.print(" ");

  Serial.print("B:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON_B));
  Serial.print(" ");

  Serial.print("C:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON_C));
  Serial.print(" ");

  Serial.print("D:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON_D));
  Serial.print(" ");

  Serial.print("E:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON_E));
  Serial.print(" ");

  Serial.print("F:");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON_F));
  Serial.print(" -- ");

  Serial.print("Position X:");
  Serial.print(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_X));
  Serial.print(" ");

  Serial.print("Y:");
  Serial.print(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_Y));
  Serial.print(" ");  

  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}
```

This program seems to work when I run the Arduino Serial Editor on the PC.
The values is coming row for row on the screen, like this .:

```
**00:58:44.434 -> Buttons A:1 B:1 C:1 D:1 E:1 F:1 -- Position X:334 Y:321**
(I can't see any wrong values in the Serial Editor. - maybe in higher speed)
```

But if I try to "do the same" with Autohotkey,  characters may be missing - some times.

Like this .:

```
 But:322
 Buttons A:1 B:1 C:1 D:1 E:1 F:1 -- Position X:334 Y:322
 334 Y:322
 Buttons A:1 B:1 C:1 D:1 E:1 F:1 -- Position X:334 Y:322
```

---

I have no idea how the communication with USB should look like in Windows 10.
(I think it is not the same as eg. Windows XP)
I have looked on this solution .: [Arduino + AutoHotKey > Serial Connection](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=128566.0)
   - Not sure I found the right Arduino.ahk
   - Maybe require Windows XP?
   - It doesn't work for me!

This tip is better (but old) .: [Arduino.ahk beta .01](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64696-some-code-arduinoahk-beta-01/)

The most of tests have been based on this link and I created the following AHK-program .:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#Singleinstance force


COM = 3
Num_Bytes = 500
Mode = 

; Initialize COM-port
COM_Port        = COM%COM%
COM_Baud        = 9600
COM_Parity  = N
COM_Data        = 8
COM_Stop        = 1
COM_DTR     = Off


FilNamn := A_ScriptDir "/Test.txt"
IfExist %FilNamn%
    FileDelete %FilNamn%


COM_Settings = %COM_Port%:baud=%COM_Baud% parity=%COM_Parity% data=%COM_Data% stop=%COM_Stop% dtr=%COM_DTR%
COM_FileHandle := Serial_Initialize(COM_Settings)

Loop 100
{   ; ReadResult := Serial_Read(COM_FileHandle, Num_Bytes, Mode)
    ReadResult := Serial_Read_Raw(COM_FileHandle, Num_Bytes, Mode)
    asciiString := Hex2ASCII(ReadResult)
    sleep 20
    FileAppend %asciiString%, %FilNamn%, UTF-8
    ; SplashTextOn 800, 100, Arduino Read, %asciiString%
    ; Sleep 1000
    ; MsgBox ,, Rad %A_LineNumber% -> %A_ScriptName%, % COM_Settings "`n`n" ReadResult "`n`n- " StrLen(ReadResult) "`n`n- " Bytes_Received "`n`n- " asciiString, 1
}
Serial_Close(COM_FileHandle)

; MsgBox ,, Rad %A_LineNumber% -> %A_ScriptName%, % COM_Settings "`n`n" ReadResult "`n`n- " StrLen(ReadResult) "`n`n- " Bytes_Received
; asciiString := Hex2ASCII(ReadResult)
; MsgBox ,, Rad %A_LineNumber% -> %A_ScriptName%, % ReadResult "`n`n"asciiString


MsgBox ,, Rad %A_LineNumber% -> %A_ScriptName%, Klart!
ExitApp

ESC::
    SplashTextOff
    Serial_Close(COM_FileHandle)
    MsgBox ,,, Programmet avslutas!, 1
    ExitApp
Return


Hex2ASCII(fHexString)
{   Loop Parse, fHexString
    NewHexString .= A_LoopField (Mod(A_Index,2) ? "" : ",")
    Loop Parse, NewHexString, `,
        ConvString .= Chr("0x" A_LoopField)
    Return ConvString
}   ;http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-211769.html#211769


;########################################################################
;###### Initialize COM Subroutine #######################################
;########################################################################
Serial_Initialize(SERIAL_Settings){
  ;Global SERIAL_FileHandle      ;uncomment this if there is a problem

  ;###### Build COM DCB ######
  ;Creates the structure that contains the COM Port number, baud rate,...
  VarSetCapacity(DCB, 28)
  BCD_Result := DllCall("BuildCommDCB"
       ,"str" , SERIAL_Settings ;lpDef
       ,"UInt", &DCB)        ;lpDCB
  If (BCD_Result <> 1){
    error := DllCall("GetLastError")
    MsgBox, There is a problem with Serial Port communication. `nFailed Dll BuildCommDCB, BCD_Result=%BCD_Result% `nLasterror=%error%`nThe Script Will Now Exit.
    ExitApp
  }

  ;###### Extract/Format the COM Port Number ######
  StringSplit, SERIAL_Port_Temp, SERIAL_Settings, `:
  SERIAL_Port_Temp1_Len := StrLen(SERIAL_Port_Temp1)  ;For COM Ports > 9 \\.\ needs to prepended to the COM Port name.
  If (SERIAL_Port_Temp1_Len > 4)                   ;So the valid names are
    SERIAL_Port = \\.\%SERIAL_Port_Temp1%             ; ... COM8  COM9   \\.\COM10  \\.\COM11  \\.\COM12 and so on...
  Else                                          ;
    SERIAL_Port = %SERIAL_Port_Temp1%
  ;MsgBox, SERIAL_Port=%SERIAL_Port%

  ;###### Create COM File ######
  ;Creates the COM Port File Handle
  ;StringLeft, SERIAL_Port, SERIAL_Settings, 4  ; 7/23/08 This line is replaced by the "Extract/Format the COM Port Number" section above.
  SERIAL_FileHandle := DllCall("CreateFile"
       ,"Str" , SERIAL_Port     ;File Name
       ,"UInt", 0xC0000000   ;Desired Access
       ,"UInt", 3            ;Safe Mode
       ,"UInt", 0            ;Security Attributes
       ,"UInt", 3            ;Creation Disposition
       ,"UInt", 0            ;Flags And Attributes
       ,"UInt", 0            ;Template File
       ,"Cdecl Int")
  If (SERIAL_FileHandle < 1){
    error := DllCall("GetLastError")
    MsgBox, There is a problem with Serial Port communication. `nFailed Dll CreateFile, SERIAL_FileHandle=%SERIAL_FileHandle% `nLasterror=%error%`nThe Script Will Now Exit.
    ExitApp
  }

  ;###### Set COM State ######
  ;Sets the COM Port number, baud rate,...
  SCS_Result := DllCall("SetCommState"
       ,"UInt", SERIAL_FileHandle ;File Handle
       ,"UInt", &DCB)          ;Pointer to DCB structure
  If (SCS_Result <> 1){
    error := DllCall("GetLastError")
    MsgBox, There is a problem with Serial Port communication. `nFailed Dll SetCommState, SCS_Result=%SCS_Result% `nLasterror=%error%`nThe Script Will Now Exit.
    Serial_Close(SERIAL_FileHandle)
    ExitApp
  }

  ;###### Create the SetCommTimeouts Structure ######
  ReadIntervalTimeout        = 0xffffffff
  ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0x00000000
  ReadTotalTimeoutConstant   = 0x00000000
  WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier= 0x00000000
  WriteTotalTimeoutConstant  = 0x00000000

  VarSetCapacity(Data, 20, 0) ; 5 * sizeof(DWORD)
  NumPut(ReadIntervalTimeout,         Data,  0, "UInt")
  NumPut(ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier,  Data,  4, "UInt")
  NumPut(ReadTotalTimeoutConstant,    Data,  8, "UInt")
  NumPut(WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier, Data, 12, "UInt")
  NumPut(WriteTotalTimeoutConstant,   Data, 16, "UInt")

  ;###### Set the COM Timeouts ######
  SCT_result := DllCall("SetCommTimeouts"
     ,"UInt", SERIAL_FileHandle ;File Handle
     ,"UInt", &Data)         ;Pointer to the data structure
  If (SCT_result <> 1){
    error := DllCall("GetLastError")
    MsgBox, There is a problem with Serial Port communication. `nFailed Dll SetCommState, SCT_result=%SCT_result% `nLasterror=%error%`nThe Script Will Now Exit.
    Serial_Close(SERIAL_FileHandle)
    ExitApp
  }

  Return SERIAL_FileHandle
}

;########################################################################
;###### Close COM Subroutine ############################################
;########################################################################
Serial_Close(SERIAL_FileHandle){
  ;###### Close the COM File ######
  CH_result := DllCall("CloseHandle", "UInt", SERIAL_FileHandle)
  If (CH_result <> 1)
    MsgBox, Failed Dll CloseHandle CH_result=%CH_result%
  Return
}

;########################################################################
;###### Write to COM Subroutines ########################################
;########################################################################
Serial_Write(SERIAL_FileHandle, Message){
  ;Global SERIAL_FileHandle
    OldIntegerFormat := A_FormatInteger

  SetFormat, Integer, DEC

  ;Parse the Message. Byte0 is the number of bytes in the array.
  StringSplit, Byte, Message, `,
  Data_Length := Byte0
  ;msgbox, Data_Length=%Data_Length% b1=%Byte1% b2=%Byte2% b3=%Byte3% b4=%Byte4%

  ;Set the Data buffer size, prefill with 0xFF.
  VarSetCapacity(Data, Byte0, 0xFF)

  ;Write the Message into the Data buffer
  i=1
  Loop %Byte0% {
    NumPut(Byte%i%, Data, (i-1) , "UChar")
    ;msgbox, %i%
    i++
  }
  ;msgbox, Data string=%Data%

  ;###### Write the data to the COM Port ######
  WF_Result := DllCall("WriteFile"
       ,"UInt" , SERIAL_FileHandle ;File Handle
       ,"UInt" , &Data          ;Pointer to string to send
       ,"UInt" , Data_Length    ;Data Length
       ,"UInt*", Bytes_Sent     ;Returns pointer to num bytes sent
       ,"Int"  , "NULL")
  If (WF_Result <> 1 or Bytes_Sent <> Data_Length)
    MsgBox, Failed Dll WriteFile to COM Port, result=%WF_Result% `nData Length=%Data_Length% `nBytes_Sent=%Bytes_Sent%
    SetFormat, Integer, %OldIntegerFormat%

    Return Bytes_Sent
}

;########################################################################
;###### Read from COM Subroutines #######################################
;########################################################################
;########################################################################
;###### Read from COM Subroutines #######################################
;########################################################################
Serial_Read(COM_FileHandle, Num_Bytes, mode = "",byref Bytes_Received = "")
{
  ;Global COM_FileHandle
  ;Global COM_Port
  ;Global Bytes_Received
  SetFormat, Integer, HEX

  ;Set the Data buffer size, prefill with 0x55 = ASCII character "U"
  ;VarSetCapacity won't assign anything less than 3 bytes. Meaning: If you
  ;  tell it you want 1 or 2 byte size variable it will give you 3.
  Data_Length  := VarSetCapacity(Data, Num_Bytes, 0x55)
  ;msgbox, Data_Length=%Data_Length%


  ;###### Read the data from the COM Port ######
  ;msgbox, COM_FileHandle=%COM_FileHandle% `nNum_Bytes=%Num_Bytes%
  Read_Result := DllCall("ReadFile"
       ,"UInt" , COM_FileHandle   ; hFile
       ,"Str"  , Data             ; lpBuffer
       ,"Int"  , Num_Bytes        ; nNumberOfBytesToRead
       ,"UInt*", Bytes_Received   ; lpNumberOfBytesReceived
       ,"Int"  , 0)               ; lpOverlapped
  ;MsgBox, Read_Result=%Read_Result% `nBR=%Bytes_Received% ,`nData=%Data%
  If (Read_Result <> 1)
  {
    MsgBox, There is a problem with Serial Port communication. `nFailed Dll ReadFile on COM Port, result=%Read_Result% - The Script Will Now Exit.
    Serial_Close(COM_FileHandle)
    Exit
  }

  ;if you know the data coming back will not contain any binary zeros (0x00), you can request the 'raw' response
  If (mode = "raw")
    Return Data

  ;###### Format the received data ######
  ;This loop is necessary because AHK doesn't handle NULL (0x00) characters very nicely.
  ;Quote from AHK documentation under DllCall:
  ;     "Any binary zero stored in a variable by a function will hide all data to the right
  ;     of the zero; that is, such data cannot be accessed or changed by most commands and
  ;     functions. However, such data can be manipulated by the address and dereference operators
  ;     (& and *), as well as DllCall itself."
  i = 0
  Data_HEX =
  Loop %Bytes_Received%
  {
    ;First byte into the Rx FIFO ends up at position 0

    Data_HEX_Temp := NumGet(Data, i, "UChar") ;Convert to HEX byte-by-byte
    StringTrimLeft, Data_HEX_Temp, Data_HEX_Temp, 2 ;Remove the 0x (added by the above line) from the front

    ;If there is only 1 character then add the leading "0'
    Length := StrLen(Data_HEX_Temp)
    If (Length =1)
      Data_HEX_Temp = 0%Data_HEX_Temp%

    i++

    ;Put it all together
    Data_HEX .= Data_HEX_Temp
  }
  ;MsgBox, Read_Result=%Read_Result% `nBR=%Bytes_Received% ,`nData_HEX=%Data_HEX%

  SetFormat, Integer, DEC
  Data := Data_HEX

  Return Data

}
;########################################################################
;###### Read from COM Subroutines #######################################
;########################################################################
Serial_Read_Raw(SERIAL_FileHandle, Num_Bytes, mode = "",byref Bytes_Received = ""){
  ;Global SERIAL_FileHandle
  ;Global SERIAL_Port
  ;Global Bytes_Received
        OldIntegerFormat := A_FormatInteger

  SetFormat, Integer, HEX

  ;Set the Data buffer size, prefill with 0x55 = ASCII character "U"
  ;VarSetCapacity won't assign anything less than 3 bytes. Meaning: If you
  ;  tell it you want 1 or 2 byte size variable it will give you 3.
  Data_Length  := VarSetCapacity(Data, Num_Bytes, 0)
  ;msgbox, Data_Length=%Data_Length%


  ;###### Read the data from the COM Port ######
  ;msgbox, SERIAL_FileHandle=%SERIAL_FileHandle% `nNum_Bytes=%Num_Bytes%
  Read_Result := DllCall("ReadFile"
       ,"UInt" , SERIAL_FileHandle   ; hFile
       ,"Str"  , Data             ; lpBuffer
       ,"Int"  , Num_Bytes        ; nNumberOfBytesToRead
       ,"UInt*", Bytes_Received   ; lpNumberOfBytesReceived
       ,"Int"  , 0)               ; lpOverlapped
  ;MsgBox, Read_Result=%Read_Result% `nBR=%Bytes_Received% ,`nData=%Data%
  If (Read_Result <> 1){
    MsgBox, There is a problem with Serial Port communication. `nFailed Dll ReadFile on COM Port, result=%Read_Result% - The Script Will Now Exit.
    Serial_Close(SERIAL_FileHandle)
    Exit
  }

  ;if you know the data coming back will not contain any binary zeros (0x00), you can request the 'raw' response
  If (mode = "raw")
    Return Data

  ;###### Format the received data ######
  ;This loop is necessary because AHK doesn't handle NULL (0x00) characters very nicely.
  ;Quote from AHK documentation under DllCall:
  ;     "Any binary zero stored in a variable by a function will hide all data to the right
  ;     of the zero; that is, such data cannot be accessed or changed by most commands and
  ;     functions. However, such data can be manipulated by the address and dereference operators
  ;     (& and *), as well as DllCall itself."
  i = 0
  Data_HEX =
  Loop %Bytes_Received% 
  {
    ;First byte into the Rx FIFO ends up at position 0

    Data_HEX_Temp := NumGet(Data, i, "UChar") ;Convert to HEX byte-by-byte
    StringTrimLeft, Data_HEX_Temp, Data_HEX_Temp, 2 ;Remove the 0x (added by the above line) from the front

    ;If there is only 1 character then add the leading "0'
    Length := StrLen(Data_HEX_Temp)
    If (Length =1)
      Data_HEX_Temp = 0%Data_HEX_Temp%

    i++

    ;Put it all together
    Data_HEX .= Data_HEX_Temp
  }
  ;MsgBox, Read_Result=%Read_Result% `nBR=%Bytes_Received% ,`nData_HEX=%Data_HEX%
    SetFormat, Integer, DEC
    Data := Data_HEX
    SetFormat, Integer, %OldIntegerFormat%

  Return Data

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you ask in an AHK forum ...

Comment: I'm trying to do it (But there may not be, as many AHK users, using Arduino?)

Comment: The percentage of AHK users knowing Arduino is certainly higher than the percentage of Arduino users knowing AHK. And, I fear it's an AHK problem.
Is the text you see in Arduino's SerialMonitor what you plan to see? If not, forget about AHK and fix it on the Arduino. If yes, then, well, good luck:)

Comment: If there's no AHK user dealing with a Serial port, AHK is eventually the wrong horse to ride? AHK stands for "Auto Hot Key", which by itself has nothing to do with Serial communication.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your time!

Has managed to get better communication between Windows and the Arduino. (with a different configuration).Made two windows in a GUI

- One where I can enter characters.
- Arduinon echoes back what is typed and returns that character to the PC
- The other show the returned characters..

It works (in 9600bps), but first I send a headline and if the baud rate increases, "strange" characters always appear at the beginning of the test.

Don't know if the serial buffer in the Arduino / PC needs to be cleared before the characters start to read in sharp mode? (how to do that?)
In the Arduino SerialMonitor I got not readable information with higher baudrate (from another test program)

My ECHO-program in the Arduino

```
int incomingByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    //Serial.print(incomingByte);
    Serial.write(incomingByte);
    }
}
```